# Video autoplay not working in iphone using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iphone, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and i using nextjs,I have video (in website) which is working/display fine in android phone but not working in Iphone, How can i fix this issue ? I tried with following cdoe

```
<video   loop autoplay='' muted>
                   <source src= { 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.vercel.app/img/video.mp4
' } type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
                   <source src={ 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/img/video.mp4
' } type="video/ogg" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
               </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `playsinline` attribute help?

Here's what I have:

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline class="video-background ">
  <source src="videos/intro-video3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: not working even in website

Comment: can you try this?  `<video autoplay muted playsinline width="250"  src="something" type="video/mp4""></video>`   -

Comment: no sir still not working

Comment: What is your ios version?

Comment: its not working on any phone ( for example 15 , 16 )

Comment: https://360-reader.com/fix-cant-stop-safari-auto-playing-videos-ios-16-iphone-ipad/

Comment: if your project is reactjs, then use `playsInline` not `playsinline`.